# Right() function in older firebird versions

Tags: firebird

What is an equivalent to `RIGHT()` (as in FB2.5)
for older versions of firebird (Firebird 2.0) without using UDFs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [SUBSTRING](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-substring.html) and [CHARACTER_LENGTH](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-substring.html) functions. Both internally available as of version FB 2.0:

```
SELECT
  IIF(CHARACTER_LENGTH(str_field) <= <right_characters_count>,
    str_field,
    SUBSTRING(str_field FROM 
      (CHARACTER_LENGTH(str_field) - <right_characters_count> + 1)))
FROM
  some_table
```

Comment: This gives me _Invalid Offset parameter xx to SUBSTRING. Only positive Integers are allowed._ for fields that are shorter than charcount. But  thanks, I will trick this to work

Comment: I have changed the example so that it will correctly works with strings shorter then desired right chars count.